# Obtaining automatic IP with network-manager fails, but static works with wicd

Tags: wireless, 15.04, network-manager, dhcp

**Update**

I've connected to my home router with `wicd` and a static IP. Thus, the problem seems to be that my laptop cannot get an IP address automatically. Hence, the main question now is: *How can I get back to automatically getting an IP?*

**Original question**

I'm faced with an interesting issue: my wireless attempts to connect, but times out eventually. This is not isolated to my home router but also the phone's wireless tether as well. USB tethering, however, works.

Prior to the issue I've been playing around with `dhclient`, releasing the current lease with `sudo dhclient -r` and getting a new IP with `sudo dhclient`. After the issue started, I've taken a look at my routers LAN devices list, and noticed a long list of IP addresses leased to my laptop. I've restarted the router, so the list has been cleared, but laptop still goes into a connect-askpassword-fail loop.

What I tried and didn't work:

- deleting everything in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` (clearly not a corrupt file for a network )
- changing the WiFi card from rtl8187se to rtl8192E (so clearly not a hardware issue)
- reinstalling NetworkManager
- Rebooting the router
- IPv6 has been disabled for months already, PowerManagement is off
- remove and reinsert module for rtl8191E

[Wireless info script pasted to ubuntu's pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11871115/)

Comment: Have your tried uninstalling **and purging** NM???  It's probably *some config file somewhere that is wrong*...  If that doesn't help, try purging the DHCP client (as you're on static IP now anyway)  (It's stuff I would do; just  grasping at straws here...)

Comment: `sudo iptables -F`?

Comment: Tough that will reset your network config as far as I understand! (stolen from [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/491729/how-to-completely-reset-ubuntu-networking-settings))

Comment: Where/how did you set the static IP? In Network Manager or in /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: @chili555 in wicd , properties tab of my home wifi

Comment: @Fabby purged NM, rebooted. Removed dhclient and reinstalled it again. Same story. Both NM and WICD hang for indefinite time on "Obtaining IP address" step. But still connecting with WICD and static IP

Comment: Would you and @Fabby please join me? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25820/discussion-with-serg-and-chili555

Comment: Weird thing,  I tried connecting to my android phone wireless tether, and i noticed that the phone reported my laptop skipping ip addresses.

Comment: **Update:** Upgraded to kernel 4.0.0-4 and reinstalled network-manager. Can get automatic IP with my Android phone, but not with  router. Still perplexed

Answer (score 3):

Many Linux wireless drivers seem to be access point sensitive. In my experience, there are several things you might try.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Next, you might try updating the driver.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

This is the same driver as https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new, but packed as dkms.

Reboot and let us have your report.

Comment: Wow! Favourited!  **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

Today I've encountered the same problem again. I've tried running `sudo dhclient -r wlan0` and then `sudo dhclient`. First time it worked, but on second one the dhcp client on my machine started declining all IP addresses in range. I've connected with static IP to my router and reset dhcp lease table, then ran `sudo service network-manager restart` and lo and behold - it works again !

I still cannot understand why `sudo dhclient -r wlan0` and `sudo dhclient` allow me to do it only once.