# iptables blocking all packets on boot

Tags: networking, configuration, iptables, firewall

A bit of time ago, i had several problems with my ethernet card and had to completely reset my network configuration (i had to rewrite and reload a new netplan.yaml, which uses Network Manager)

Side effect to this (i think, it might've been caused by another fix i tried) is that i couldn't access internet anymore. A solution provided in [How to completely reset ubuntu networking settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491729/how-to-completely-reset-ubuntu-networking-settings) is to flush iptables rules, which indeed works, but is a "temporary fix" as in I have, like user joe_inz in the original thread, have to do it on every startup (which is not convenient).

Here is the output of `sudo iptables -L` on every boot :

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

As you can see, it basically blocks everything

After digging down a bit and understanding what iptables is (and, consequently, also understanding how having no rules at all is not a great idea), I took the "beginner" set of rules provided here https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/iptables, installed iptables-persistent, and saved them up in /etc/iptables/rules.v4

Here is how the rules looks after the first importation (and how they *should* look like) :

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = multicast
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID tcp flags:FIN,PSH,URG/FIN,PSH,URG
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN,RST
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = broadcast
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ! ctstate INVALID
```

However, after rebooting, I had same as before no internet access, so i rechecked the rules and they looked like this :

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = multicast
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID tcp flags:FIN,PSH,URG/FIN,PSH,URG
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN,RST
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = broadcast
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ! ctstate INVALID
```

For no apparent reason, there were *again* rules that drop every single packet

`iptables-restore` does at least restore the set of rules i took online, which is way better than nothing (so i'll use that instead of a complete flush as i did before), but does anyone know why would my laptop drop everything by default and how to fix that ?

PS : Also if you'd have any tips on how i could fine-tune this set of rules it would be greatly welcomed, as having a solid firewall is not negligible.

PPS : I am on Ubuntu 20.04 if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem seems to have been fixed by itself by a recent iptables-persistent update, but I'm not even sure. I just wanted to say it returned to normal now