# How to completely reconfigure network settings from scratch in 20.04?

Tags: networking

I have the problem that my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop stopped playing nicely with the network it is connected to via ethernet after some credentials change. Everything works nicely if I boot from a USB stick into a vanilla 20.04.

Hence I assume, that somehow some config file must be stuck in a dysfunctional state, so how do I remove really everything and reconfigure my network adapter from scratch?

I've read and tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491729/how-to-completely-reset-ubuntu-networking-settings) and [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restart-network-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa) and nothing worked.

Comment: Is this a server or a desktop? Ethernet or wireless? Please edit your question to add these details.

Comment: good point, done and thanks

Comment: Hello. What does this mean? stopped playing nicely Actual errors and or more info is required. Please explain what was changed. With out all the details very hard to give a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the details of the old, now superceded, connection are stored in Network Manager. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

Is there any improvement?