# 101: Network is unreachable when i run sudo apt update

Tags: networking, apt, updates

I try to run `sudo apt update` but it's not working

```
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
More errors like that...
```

I changed the dns server to 8.8.8.8. VPN does not help, connected to Canada and US.

Also after an error my internet is disconnected and only a reboot helps

Ubuntu version is 20.04
And I use WSL

Edit: I also disabled ipv6 but it's still not working

Comment: It looks like you are having a connection problem. Try this command:

    **ping 8.8.8.8**

and after wating for a while, type **Ctrl + c** to see if you are having package loss.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491729/how-to-completely-reset-ubuntu-networking-settings/492023#492023?newreg=812b24f0b0364b889395a95225f08c27) and the answers there to reset networking, in particular the top answer and the one below. Using the following worked for me:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo dhclient -r
sudo dhclient
```